# Using a collection of interfaces, and persisting only the implementations

Tags: java, hibernate

So, here's what I'm trying to do, with simple sample code for the demonstration:

Interface:

```
public interface Shape{
    String getName();
    void setName(String name);
}
```

Class:

```
@Entity
public class Circle{
    @Id
    private int id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    private ShapeBox box;

    @Override
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public ShapeBox getBox(){
        return box;
    }

    public void setBox(ShapeBox box){
        this.box = box;
    }
}
```

Collection Class:

```
@Entity
public class ShapeBox{
    @Id
    private int boxId

    @OneToMany (mappedBy="box", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Shape> shapeList = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Shape> getShapeList(){
        return shapeList;
    }

    public void setShapeList(List<Shape> shapeList){
        this.shapeList = shapeList;
    }

    public int getBoxId(){
        return boxId;
    }

    public void setBoxId(int boxId){
        this.boxId = boxId;
    }

}
```

I literally just wrote all of this directly into this website, so if there are minor syntax errors I apologize.

So, the point is, I want to be able to use a collection of subclasses of Shape within the ShapeBox class. ShapeBox has a List of the Shape interface, but its contents are all subclasses of Shape. All the subclasses will be properly mapped for hibernate.

So, I realize I'm not the first one to attempt to do this, I've looked at some other answers on this site, but ultimately I feel like someone had to at least figure out an ugly workaround for this, if nothing else.

What I've seen so far:
@MappedSuperclass - useful for bypassing the exception for an unmapped entity, but still get the exception for the mappedBy property referring to an unknown entity.

@Entity on the interface - if all getters are marked as transient, this can have more or less the same effect as @MappedSuperclass, with the same issues.

targetEntity property - the only way I've seen to make this work, using this to point to the implementation. However it creates a dependency on that specific implementation, which reduces the flexibility of polymorphism.

Do I have any other options here? Anything creative that can be done to work around this?

Comment: Maybe I'm not following... What's the issue with `@MappedSuperclass`?

Comment: In ShapeBox, the shapeList's type is Shape. It throws an exception because it can't find the mappedBy column in Shape. "Use of OneToMany or ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class"